# Don't allow multiple dots using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have Regex that should validate some number:

```
\b\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,3}[.]?\d{1,3}[,]?\d{0,2}\b
```

Number format is something like: `123.456,00`

And it works almost perfect, except it allows `123...456,00` and I would like to prevent that. Any help or advice would be great.

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your expected outputs?

Comment: Also it allows `123...456,00` because the number of your digits are between 0 and 3 so it will allows 3 dot.

Comment: Do you really have to check for word boundaries? Are your strings tested separately, or are they part of a larger input? What format do you validate? `xxx.xxx.xxx,yy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be I'm wrong, but I guess you're looking for:

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{0,2}\b
```

This matches:

- `1,00`
- `1.234,56`
- `123.456.789,01`

Comment: This regex will not match `123.333`. Is it OK?

Comment: It will only match `23.456,00` from `1.23.456,00` which isn't correct. Also check with input `123,456` it matches only `123,`

Comment: @anubhava: You're right but `1.23.456,00` is not a valid input (the dot is the thousand separator); `123,456` is not valid because there are up to 2 digits for decimal part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **negative lookahead** to avoid matching numbers with more than one dot:

```
/^(?!(?:.*?\.){2})\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,3}[.]?\d{1,3}[,]?\d{0,2}$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uP3zY4/1)

`(?!(?:.*?\.){2})` is the negative lookahead that means fail the match if there are 2 dots present in the input.

---

**EDIT:** Based on comments below if you just want to allow 2 adjacent dots then use:

```
/^(?!.*?\.{2})\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,3}[.]?\d{1,3}[,]?\d{0,2}$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/uP3zY4/2)

Comment: It is easy with `^` and `$`. Try with `\b` :)

Comment: I think this regex can be written more precise and there is no need to make it more complicate and inefficient !!!

Comment: Yes I agree @Kasra, I didn't make any change in OP's regex, just added a negative lookahead.

Comment: This work, but it will not allow 1.234.567,00 niter.

Comment: Is `1.234.567,00` a valid input with 2 dots?

Comment: Yes, dot is used as separator for thousand in some countries.

Comment: Yes I have already updated the answer to allow those formats.